# PHP SimpleXMLElement - accessing values with in an element

Tags: php, simplexml, kml

I am reading a KML file in php using SimpleXMLElement class. The last elements in the tree look like the example below (var_dump of php object say $element):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "featurecla"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Admin-0 country"
}
```

How do I access "Admin-0 country" value in php?

I have tried both $element->children() and $element->attributes() and only be able to access  "featurecla" only.

Comment: I think you can use `echo $element;` or get the value using `$val =  (string)$element;`

Comment: Tried that, echo (string) outputs string, which needs to be processed, rataher than a structured array or object.

Comment: If you found your solution, please mark your question as "closed".

Comment: Hi! The convention here is to keep Questions and Answers separate - even if you're answering your own question, please do so by filling in the Answer box below and marking the answer as "accepted", rather than editing the Question box above.

Comment: @IMSoP - Thanks. Have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found the solution**

Turns out I was not examining the KML file properly, and just looking at php var_dump outputs to understand the data structure. The KML file data looked like below:

```
<Folder><name>ne_50m_admin_0_countries</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Zimbabwe</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#ne_50m_admin_0_countries">
        <SimpleData name="featurecla">Admin-0 country</SimpleData>
```

In the PHP code, I was using the code below to access the SimpleData:

```
foreach($xmlContent->Document->Folder->children() as $Placemark){
        print_r("<h1>".(string)$Placemark->name."</h1>");
        foreach ($Placemark->ExtendedData->SchemaData->SimpleData as $element){
            var_dump($element); //output shown above
            var_dump($element->children());
            var_dump($element->attributes());
                        }
    }
```

After looking at the raw kml file, I was able to access the required information:

```
foreach($xmlContent->Document->Folder->children() as $Placemark){
        print_r("<h1>".(string)$Placemark->name."</h1>");

        foreach ($Placemark->ExtendedData->SchemaData->SimpleData as $element){

            echo $element->attributes()."=>";
            echo $element."<br>";           
            //output featurecla=>Admin-0 country
        }
    }
```